# Hypernym for "necklace", "bracelet" and "anklet"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

Each is an item of jewelry that is primarily distinguished by the body part around which it is wrapped. *Jewelry* is too generic a term, since it would include earrings as well, which are not wrapped around the wearer.

Example:

> She preferred the versatility of [blunks], which could be on display as a necklace during dinner, but safely hidden around her ankle or wrist while walking home through the city.

Comment: Would you include a ring, since that is wrapped around a finger?

Comment: How about *chains*?

Comment: As Peter Shor suggested, "Chains" was my first thought, with the caveat that bangles and chokers would be exceptions to this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Circlet* may work for you; it's a bit shaky, but jewelry houses clearly often use it to refer to pieces intended to be worn as necklaces, and some sources at least define anklets and bracelets as types of circlet.

Comment: How is this the accepted answer when mine was posted first (and includes the required citation)?

Comment: Granted, I'm no jeweler, but I've never heard of this usage.  I've only ever heard the term "circlet" used as something that goes on top of the head, usually a crown.

Comment: @MarvMills why does it matter? the important thing is that a good answer is accepted. it's up to the asker to determine that. it sounds like you're letting ego get in the way ...

Comment: @MarvMills The StackExchange timestamp showed this as being posted prior to yours, which is why I selected it. The changes often propagate unevenly, but the timestamps are preserved correctly. Thanks for the answer, though.

Comment: In my experience a circlet must be of solid construction (not a chain) and is worn on the head like a tiara.

Comment: [*Circlet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circlet) is from the Latin for "open crown". Plus one for *like a tiara*, @Phil

Comment: @jimm101 Bu the timestamp of this answer is over a minute later than Marv's. And like other commenters, I don't think circlet is a good fit to begin with.

Answer (score 19):

There is ['circlet'](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/circlet?s=t)

> noun
>
> 3 - a ring-shaped ornament, especially for the head.
>
> *www.dictionary.com*

Comment: Since this answer was the first one to post, So, +1

Answer (score 3):

The term **bangle** could definitely be used to encompass anklets and bracelets, but perhaps not necklaces. I'm not sure there is a word which describes concisely all three

Comment: there is, it's called **bling** but i don't think it fits here

Comment: Bangles can be earrings as well.

Answer (score 3):

I don’t know much jewelry terminology (and I don’t know anyone whose wrist and ankle circumferences match that of their neck), but this [O’La Vi Jewelry ad](http://www.olavijewelry.us/Fashion-Jewelry-New-York-NY.html) might be talking about what you’re asking about and it uses “wraparound” as a single word together with “jewelry” (= “wraparound jewelry”) to describe “[jewelry] that contours to [the] shape ... [of] the trait you wish to emphasize.”

Unless the context was absolutely clear, you’d have to use it together with “jewelry” (so I guess that’s two words) because “[wraparound](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wraparound)” used by itself would refer to a type of clothing, e.g., skirts. (from Merriam-Webster)

Comment: A choker can be looped multiple times around a wrist.

Comment: @jimm101 Ahhh, mystery solved. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for is jewelry.

Comment: The OP explains why *jewelry* is not a suitable option in the question.