# Hypernym for jewelry and cosmetics

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

I ask for an online shop that I'm helping set up which is going to sell jewelry, soaps, skin care products and other cosmetics. I'm looking for a word that encompasses all of these things, perhaps to be used in the name of the shop. For example, the name "Devi's Cosmetics" or "Devi Cosmetics" was considered but I then realized that "cosmetics" doesn't cover the full scope of what the shop will be offering.

Comment: I don't think there is an established word here. Maybe something novel, like "beauty aids", or "appearance enhancements"?

Comment: Yeah, I'm going with Dan Bron here, there isn't an agreed [**hyperonym**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyponymy_and_hypernymy), you'll have to coin a phrase, a gimmick yourself "BB = body beautiful" or "jeweletics"  or anything your imagination suggests.

Comment: *beauty accessories*? It does seem like there should be a word for this, BTW.

Comment: loosely related: [A word for clothes, shoes, accessories?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35427/a-word-for-clothes-shoes-accessories) and [Hypernym for “necklace”, “bracelet” and “anklet”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/283520/hypernym-for-necklace-bracelet-and-anklet)

Comment: If this helps... in Italian the term *‘profumeria’* (see [**Google images.it**)](https://www.google.it/search?q=profumeria+significato&biw=1242&bih=535&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8xt_4y8fRAhUJXhQKHSYEDYQQ_AUIBygC#tbm=isch&q=negozio+profumeria+) refers to shops that not only sell perfumes, but also theatrical jewellery, cosmetics, and skincare products

Comment: adornment, perhaps?

Comment: Or "woman (*women's*) corner" ?

Comment: Devi's Stylings, Style Boutique  (too much like a hair salon?)  Devi's StyleStop,  Style-joint, StyleOutlet,  Style-exchange, ... sorry .. don't think thats getting there

Comment: @Graffito No-one puts *(women's)* in the corner!

Answer (score 1):

The word that first came to my non-native English speaker mind is **a French word, parure**.

One of its definition is given, in [ATILF](http://atilf.atilf.fr/):

> Action de parer quelqu'un, de se parer ; fait d'être paré

or

> Action to adorn someone, to adorn oneself; being/getting adorned

A little text, from De l'éducation des femmes ([archive.org](https://archive.org/details/delducationdesf00baudgoog) or [text](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/De_l%E2%80%99%C3%A9ducation_des_femmes)) by Laclos says:

> De la parure. Nous connaissons deux sortes de parures; l'une, qui consiste à tenir le corps dans l'état de perfection dont il est susceptible; l'autre, à tirer le parti le plus avantageux des vêtements ou ornements dont le besoin, le caprice ou la raison, ont consacré l'usage (...). La parure est non seulement l'art de tirer parti des dons de la nature, mais encore celui de leur prêter les charmes de l'imagination
>
> Of adornment [one possible translation]. We know two kinds of ornaments; The one, which consists in holding the body in the state of perfection of which it is susceptible; The other, to make the most advantageous use of the garments or ornaments whose need, caprice, or reason have consecrated usage. The adornment is not only the art of taking advantage of the gifts of nature, but also that of lending them the charms of the imagination

The part "holding the body in the state of perfection of which it is susceptible" could fit to soaps, skin care products and other cosmetics. So **parure** in the French sense could suit. But parure in English seems to be restricted to jewelry:

> [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parure): a matched set of ornaments (as jewelry)

Adornment may be too wide:

> [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adornment): something added to make a person or thing more attractive. The adornment of the walls with her paintings. 
>   Her room doesn't have any unnecessary adornments.
>   The entrance to the building has little adornment.

So I would also propose **finery**. It used to describe *fineness; beauty* (somewhat obsolete) and also *ornament; decoration* ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/finery)).

From several sources gathered at [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/finery):

- American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language: Elaborate adornment, especially fine clothing and accessories.
- GNU version of the Collaborative International Dictionary of English: Fineness; beauty. n. Ornament; decoration, jewels.
- WordNet 3.0: elaborate or showy attire and accessories